# Error setting map marker based on returned business name in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the following to show a corresponding marker image based on the returned business name using Google Places and Maps:

```
    if (name.contains("walmart")) {
    mIcon = R.drawable.ic_wm_poi;
} if (name.contains("speedco")) {
    mIcon = R.drawable.ic_poi_speedco;
}
```

The logcat shows "Unkown icon: business name" which does correspond with one of my if statements but doesn't show the corresponding icon. I've tried using if/else and switch statements. I've also tried name.contains, name.equals and name.contentEquals. For example, if I search "Walmart", the response returns the business name "Walmart" as shown in the logcat, and the marker shows the name "Walmart" once clicked yet the corresponding icon doesn't show. I am setting the marker icon like so:

`markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(markerIcon(placeName)));`

**EDIT**
After implementing crickets' comment, the icons for the various locations still don't show. This is what I have:

```
    public class MarkerIcons {

    public static HashMap<String, Integer> poiIcons;

    public static HashMap<String, Integer> getpoiIcons(){
        poiIcons = new HashMap<>();
        poiIcons.put("Walmart", R.drawable.ic_wm_poi);
        poiIcons.put("Walmart Supercenter", R.drawable.ic_wm_poi);
        poiIcons.put("Walmart Neighborhood Market", R.drawable.ic_wm_poi);

        return poiIcons;
    }

    public static Integer markerIcon(String name){
        String TAG_MI = "marker";
        Log.d(TAG_MI, "Loc Name: " + name);
        int mIcon = 0;
        if(getpoiIcons().containsKey(name)){
            mIcon = getpoiIcons().get(name).intValue();
            return mIcon;
        }else{
            mIcon = R.drawable.default_marker;
            return mIcon;
        }
    }

}
```

How I am calling these functions:

**Get Place Class**

```
    public class GetNearbyBusinessData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

    private String TAG = "getplace";

    private String googlePlacesData;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground entered");
            mMap = (GoogleMap) params[0];
            url = (String) params[1];
            DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
            googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground Exit");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return googlePlacesData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute Entered");
        List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList;
        DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
        nearbyPlacesList =  dataParser.parse(result);
        ShowNearbyBusiness(nearbyPlacesList);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute Exit");
        Log.d(TAG, result);
    }

    private void ShowNearbyBusiness(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nearbyPlacesList.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Entered into showing business");
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlacesList.get(i);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));
            String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(placeName + "-" + vicinity);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(markerIcon(placeName)));
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            //move map camera
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

After setting break points for the `markerIcon` method and the line that calls the `markerIcon` method, the debug log shows that the returned response string is in fact "Walmart". Which is matching the `key` value in the HashMap. The returned icon for the marker is being returned as "0" though. It isn't returning the "value" from the hash map. I am setting the marker icon using this line:

`mIcon = getpoiIcons().get(name).intValue();`

Given the options available, I assumed that getting the matching "key" (in this case the string "name") would return its int "value". Am I missing something?

Even though the logcat shows the returned business names of Walmart, Walmart Supercenter and Walmart Neighborhood Market, it still shows the default marker. I have no idea why it is not showing the correct marker icon. Also, if it helps, my marker icons are vector images.

Comment: `map.put("walmart", R.drawable.ic_wm_poi); mIcon = map.get("walmart"); if (mIcon != null) { showIcon(mIcon) );`

Comment: @cricket_007 Perfect! Thank you! I'll give that a try and see if that solves the problem. For future reference, is it possible that the icon's weren't showing because my if/else tree was too large?

Comment: Hey, still missing the [mcve], though. How are you calling these functions? Where is the `markerOptions` value?

Comment: @cricket_007 Corrected. Please see edit.

Comment: Okay 1) Is that really a "minimal" example? 2) Why are you not just using the Android Places API? https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start

Comment: I was attempting to give as much information as possible to duplicate my issue. I chose not to use the Android Places API because it didn't seem to suit my specific needs.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Basically my question is: Is the network request the issue?  If it is, what data do you get back? If not, then have you tried to hard-code some values into your app, and do the icons show?

Comment: the response from the network is fine, I get the business names as expected. According to my logcat. What doesn't show are the icons for the Walmarts even though the business names match the key value. It shows the default icon from the if/else statement

Comment: I've tried setting the marker icon directly as the walmart icon regardless of the return and it works but when I try to pass it through the HashMap I get the default icon

Comment: It is case-sensitive, by the way. `markerIcon("Walmart")` will work with the code you've shown. `markerIcon("walmart")` gets the default icon.

Comment: I thought that as well and that's why I changed the HashMap values to match the returned business names case-sensitive, as is shown above. Unfortunately, it still returned the default icon.

Comment: Put a `Log.d("PlaceName", String.format("[%s]", placeName));` before you use `markerIcon(placeName)` and make sure it says exactly `[Walmart]` in the logs

Comment: I did. It shows the business names in the responses as matching the keys in the hashmap that's why I am so confused as to why it isn't working if they match

Comment: Alright, then set a breakpoint within your `markerIcon` function. I can only give suggestions here. I can't run your code.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that on the morning

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok. I set a breakpoint for my `markerIcon` method and for the line that calls the `markerIcon` method. The returned string `name` is consistent throughout. Yet `mIcon` still returns "0" even though the key matches the returned place_name.

Comment: check my answer. try it, or we will try another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think every thing work fine. but the error is, so far i have seen your code is,

```
 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(markerIcon(placeName)));
```

what you want to do is,

```
 BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(markerIcon(placeName)));
 markerOptions.icon(icon);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just tried that. It still crashes with a NullPointerException. Breakpoint still shows mIcon returns as 0

Comment: what was the error before update this code? can you post the error log

Comment: post this method. dataParser.parse(result);

Comment: The error was originally, NullPointerException on 'markerIcon(String name)'. Out of curiosity, I changed the icon integer to a PNG image and it works now. I guess vector images don't work. I had stated that I was using vectors in my post

Answer (score 0):

U have function in separate class try this

```
MarkerIcons.markerIcon(placeName))
```

or update me if ur problem is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the answers that were given and attempting to debug my code to find what was wrong, I found the error.

For anyone else that may have the same issue of the marker icons not showing, through trial and error I had found that you cannot use vector images that are in xml format as your markers. Once I switched them all over to png files, every icon showed without flaw.

Hope this answer helps someone else in the future. Thank you everyone for your contributions.